# System.import loading module but not executing any code within it

Tags: systemjs, es6-module-loader

I've got a file named `index.js` which looks like this:

```
import Backbone from 'backbone'
import _ from 'underscore'
import $ from 'jquery'

console.log("blah")
export default {...}
```

In my `index.html` I've got:

```
<script>
  System.import('index');
</script>
```

But what's baffling me is that I can see the file being loaded (in the dev tools network panel) but the `console.log` is never run.  If this is the case, how am I to bootstrap my application?

Several online tutorials suggest bootstrapping it in the System.import file but how can that be done if the code isn't executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a `.then()` to the `System.import` with three anonymous functions, all with just a `debugger` and found that the `import $ from 'jquery'` was timing out because I didn't have the library installed.  I removed the import declaration and the app was still trying to load jquery, so I installed it and it fixed the issue.